# Recyclerview gridlayout manager showing unnecessary space

Tags: android, gridview, android-recyclerview, android-gridview, gridlayoutmanager

I am trying to show custom layout in recyclerview in a gridview layout manager, but after 2nd row onwards extra space is coming into the border.
Hence my question is how to remove that extra space and what could be the reason behind the space ?

Attaching image and code snippets.

[image]

**Custom Item View Layout**

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/frameLayout"   
android:layout_margin="2dp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:src="@drawable/redcap"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_info"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/img_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center|bottom|left"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:textColor="@color/primary_dark"
        android:textSize="@dimen/TvTextSizeNormal"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Adapter Code**

```
 public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
   
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   
    View view = null;
    final Item item = mItems.get(position);
    
    if (convertView == null) {
     
     Holder holder = new Holder();
     view = View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.myItemView, null);
     holder.img_content =  view.findViewById(R.id.img_content);
     holder.tv_info = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_info);
     view.setTag(holder);
        
    } else {
        view = convertView;
    }

     Holder holder = (Holder) view.getTag();
     holder.tv_info.setText(item.getCategoryName());
     Picasso.get().load(url).fit().into(holder.img_content);
     return view;
    
   }

 }
```

**MainActivity**

```
    myAdapter= new MyAdapter(MainActivity.this,subCategoryList);
    recyclerGridView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,2));
    recyclerGridView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

Comment: May I ask why are you extending BaseAdapter instead of RecyclerView.Adapter?

Comment: define the image's height this will fix the issue. ie.        android:layout_height="200dp"

Comment: @ChandanPednekar hi  , yes there are few functionalities in the original code which are easy for us to implement in BaseAdapter hence taken BaseAdapter.

Comment: @NehaK . I cannot give static height.

Comment: Because this line: ***android:scaleType="fitCenter"***

Comment: @HoàngVũAnh what replacement shall i do ?

Comment: Change this line: ***android:scaleType="centerCrop"***. I think it's work fine

Comment: @HoàngVũAnh centerCrop is zooming the images and not showing entire image completely.

Comment: yep, so you can set height for image or use Flexbox Layout .Link here: https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout

Comment: what height do you want? runtime , according to image height?

Comment: ratio or by srcImage height?

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same layout in one of my projects

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

and remove `.fit()` from Picasso call

Answer (score 0):

Use following class, this will adjust ImageView's height according to the actualImage :

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;

public class ManageHeightByWidthImageView extends androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView {

    public int width = -1;
    public int height = -1;

    public ManageHeightByWidthImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ManageHeightByWidthImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ManageHeightByWidthImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

        Drawable d = getDrawable();
        if (d != null) {

            int imageIntrinsicWidth = d.getIntrinsicWidth();
            int imageIntrinsicHeight = d.getIntrinsicHeight();

            Log.d(ManageHeightByWidthImageView.class.getName(), imageIntrinsicWidth + " -- " + imageIntrinsicHeight);

            int w = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
            int h = w * d.getIntrinsicHeight() / d.getIntrinsicWidth();

            width = w;
            height = h;
            try {
                setMeasuredDimension(w, h);
            } catch (NullPointerException ignored) {
            }
        } else {
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        }
    }

}
```

How to use inside your code :

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.proportionlImageView.ManageHeightByWidthImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:minHeight="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/redcap"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_info"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/img_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center|bottom|left"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:textColor="@color/primary_dark"
        android:textSize="@dimen/TvTextSizeNormal"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```